# Spring Batch reading from 2 different databases

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am working on a Spring Batch application with a job that works with around 7 million elements. So far, the job is set up to read from a SQL database, apply some processing and write to a mongo database.
I am now implementing a change detection mechanism wherein after processing if the data of a specific element is the same as the previous run, I don't want to write it into mongo. In order to do this, I need to access the output of the previous run in the processor so I know when to exclude it from being written.
Since the processor is called for every element, I cannot have a repository call in the processor. Looking for suggestions on how I could solve this.

I am thinking of 2 different options right now but I'm not sure if this aligns with the best practices:

1. Replace the existing JDBC SQL reader with a custom reader that first reads from the SQL database and then from mongo by querying only those elements that were read from SQL. This way I can pass the input data from SQL and the previous run's output into the processor.
2. Keep the existing SQL reader and use one of the batch event listeners (chunk listener, item read listener). For example, I could create an item read listener where once items are read, I can query mongo for those items and store that data in an in-memory cache and access that in the processor. I am worried about how this would affect multi-threading however.